# Size of Subclass

Tags: java, inheritance

If I have a classes A_1, ... A_m extending a class B, then the size of an object of A_i is at least the size of an object of B.

If I now declare an array 
    B collB[] = new B[1];

then how much space is allocated?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's creating an array with one element. It'll probably be about 20 bytes, and will vary depending on the JVM you're using (e.g. 32-bit vs 64-bit).

It won't vary *at all* by the number of fields in `B`, or `A`, or anything like that - because you're not actually creating any *instances* of `B`. You're only creating an array, whose sole element will be a null reference initially.